# CSS Selector - Selecting text inside a "p" tag with 4 texts inside and separated with <br>

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, selector

I need help in CSS Selector. Here is my problem, I want to extract a text inside a "p" tag with multiple texts inside and separated with `<br>` I only need 1 line of text to get the return of
   "Company Name: Corkery Consulting"
or if possible
   "Corkery Consulting"

```
<p class="">Company Name: Corkery Consulting<br>Phone: +61 2 9906 6636<br>Fax: +61 2 9906 6634<br>Web: <a target="_blank" href="http://www.corkeryconsulting.com" class="">http://www.corkeryconsulting.com</a></p>
```

I tried this:
   "p:first-of-type" and "p:nth-of-type(1)"

But it gives me all the texts result.
   "Company Name: Corkery Consulting Phone: +61 2 9906 6636 Fax: +61 2 9906 6634 Web: http://www.corkeryconsulting.com"

I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: <p class="">Company Name: Corkery Consulting<br>Phone: +61 2 9906 6636<br>Fax: +61 2 9906 6634<br>Web: <a target="_blank" href="http://www.corkeryconsulting.com" class="">http://www.corkeryconsulting.com</a></p>

Comment: Please share the HTML and CSS in the question

Comment: Done :) adding the Html

Comment: Where does the content of the `<p>` come from? Do you have control of it? The best practice is to mark things to describe _what they are_, like `<p class="co-record">Company Name: <span class="co-name">Corkery Consulting</span><br>Phone: <span class="co-phone">+61 (etc)</span>...</p>` then you can extract pieces from it.

Answer (score 3):

```css
p::first-line {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="">Company Name: Corkery Consulting<br>Phone: +61 2 9906 6636<br>Fax: +61 2 9906 6634<br>Web: <a target="_blank" href="http://www.corkeryconsulting.com" class="">http://www.corkeryconsulting.com</a></p>
```

You could use this approach. Or wrap first line into span and than style it like this:

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="">Company Name: <span class="selected">Corkery Consulting</span><br>Phone: +61 2 9906 6636<br>Fax: +61 2 9906 6634<br>Web: <a target="_blank" href="http://www.corkeryconsulting.com" class="">http://www.corkeryconsulting.com</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to add `span` tag to your code:

```css
p span {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p class="">Company Name: <span>Corkery Consulting</span><br>Phone: +61 2 9906 6636<br>Fax: +61 2 9906 6634<br>Web: <a target="_blank" href="http://www.corkeryconsulting.com" class="">http://www.corkeryconsulting.com</a></p>
```

If you need more specific selector, add class to your `p` and/or `span`.

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for answering, but the HTML is already fixed and no need to change the color. just want a code or CSS Selector that will return 
"Company Name: Corkery COnsulting" 
or if possible 
"Corkery Consulting"

I tried this code 
"p:first-of-type" and "p:nth-of-type(1)"

But it only returns me all the text inside the "p"

Comment: I think i made a mistake in using the right word, i used select instead of extracting the text

Comment: @Renz If you want to extract the text, where are you going to use it? In javascript?

Comment: I want it in my CSV format. But i want to figure out first how to return only the text I want. I know you guys can help me here.

Comment: @Renz You can't extract it with CSS only, so without knowing how are you going to continue process, it's hard to answer exactly.

Comment: Honestly I dont realy know about codes, Im practicing. 
I use this code.
p:first-of-type" and "p:nth-of-type(1)
I dont know what language is that. Im sure you understand that.
and it gives me the return of all texts.
"Company Name: Corkery Consulting Phone: +61 2 9906 6636 Fax: +61 2 9906 6634 Web: http://www.corkeryconsulting.com"

and if I try this

p:nth-of-type(1) a
It gives me this return
"http://www.corkeryconsulting.com"

I want the return of 
"Company Name: Corkery Consulting"
or
"Corkery Consulting"
If possible.

Any ways you know how to do that?